# How to setup MichaelMackus/SyliusSubscriptionBundle in Sylius 1.3

Tags: sylius

How to setup `MichaelMackus/SyliusSubscriptionBundle` in `Sylius 1.3`

I have already setup this [repo](https://github.com/Richtermeister/Sylius/tree/subscription-bundle) 
but I don't know how to make product subscribable from the admin dashboard.

This implementation is for `Sylius v1.0`, a lot has been changed now.

I want to see this work for either version of sylius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look into the bundle once and came to the conclusion that it never worked.  I might be wrong but for sure I can say, it will not work for 1.3 because Sylius migrated to Symfony Flex.

It accesses properties which are not there nor will be implemented by the bundle like `OrderItem::getSubscription()` used [here](https://github.com/MichaelMackus/SyliusSubscriptionBundle/blob/master/EventListener/UpdateSubscriptionsListener.php#L44) but is not defined.

---

There is an [PR](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/385) on Github to integrate this bundle into Sylius and takes care of the aforementioned issue but the PR is outdated as well.

I assume you have integrate Subscription on your own.

Comment: Yes I got it, but I want to see it working once, so how to add subscription property to product from the admin dashboard in Sylius v1.0